# type modifier is not allowed for type "geometry" when updating DB with postgis via geoalchemy2 & alembic

Tags: sqlalchemy, postgis, postgresql-9.1, alembic, geoalchemy2

My alembic update script for adding a new postgis geometry point looks like this:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
import geoalchemy2 as ga

def upgrade():
    op.add_column('stuff', sa.Column('my_location', ga.Geometry('POINT', management=True)))


def downgrade():
    pass
```

When I run the script via

```
alembic upgrade head
```

the following error occurs

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) type modifier is not allowed for type "geometry"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE events ADD COLUMN location geometry(POINT,-1)
```

I am using postgres 9.1, postgis 1.5, sqlalchemy 1.0.9, geoalchemy2 0.2.6.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Postgis 1.5, which does not support type modifier for the `geometry` type.

How to fix the issue: Postgis 1.5 is currently quite old, so upgrade to Postgis 2.x

If for same reason you cannot upgrade your Postgis installation, the correct way to add a geometry column is using the function [AddGeometryColumn()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html). The SQL statement looks so:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','events','geom',0,'POINT',2);
```

where the arguments mean:

1) schema name, 
2) table name, 
3) column name,
4) srid,
5) type,
6) dimension.

However you are already using the correct flag for adding geometry column in Postgis 1.5: `management=True`. In accordance to to [documentation](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2/types.html#geoalchemy2.types._GISType), this should force SqlAlchemy to use the AddGeometryColumn() syntax. Maybe the error is coming from Alembic an not from GeoAlchemy?